# How to stretch div height from header to bottom of the window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a construction as you can see below.
2.Div should be stretched from header to bottom of the window.
By the way I'm using a layout which includes "Header" and "Footer" so "Header" and "Footer" come from layout. When the page was opened, just 1.div and 2.div should be visible like that then scrolling it should follow other divs.

[image]

Comment: provide some html and css you have done

Comment: could you place your tried html and css code...

Comment: Actually, I have done just layout page and it includes just header and footer thats all. 

.header{ padding-bottom: 31px;position: relative;}
.footer{display:block;position:relative;}

<body>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="2.div">
</div>
<div class="3.div">
</div>

<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>

I confused how can I make 2.div like that without percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a header that has a relative height, you could do this trick with JQuery;

Set the height of the `.body` element, by subtracting the `.header` height from the `<body>` tag height.

```js
$('.bodycontent').height(
    $('body').height() - $('.header').height()
);
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

.header {
  background-color:red;
}

.bodycontent {
  background-color:blue;
}

.third {
  height:30%;
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  header
</div>

<div class="bodycontent">
  
</div>

<div class="third">
  
</div>
```

Comment: But header should not has static height